# Documentation edit reviewing should show the reviews of others

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When you reject a documentation proposed change, you can enter a reason why you're rejecting it. However, if you're reviewing something that someone else rejected, you can't see why they did. Or even *that* they did.

This would be useful in cases where there is a subtle bug in code that someone caught, but you didn't notice. If you could see that someone else rejected it and why, then you can add your voice to make sure it doesn't go through.

Comment: Edit history needs  a tree view more like Q/A history but with more features also like filtering rejections, filtering users etc. Loading new page to see each edit is silly